# MySQL Get last inserted ID Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'insert_id'

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

If i try to get the last inserted ID, i get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'insert_id'
```

Here is the part of the Code:

```
class Db extends MySQLi {
    private static $ins;
    public static $num_rows;
    public static $inserted_id;

    public function query($q)
    {
        if(!$res = parent::query($q))
            throw new DBException(sprintf("Error: %s", $this->error));

            $this->inserted_id = parent::insert_id;
            return $res;
        }
}
```

I also tryed:

```
parent::$insert_id
$this->insert_id
```

Comment: You save to property `inserted_id`, but read `insert_id`. Those are different names.

Comment: Yes i try to save the parent::insert_id to the "inserted_id". But the Error belongs to parent::insert_id.

Comment: The correct form is `$this->insert_id`. It is only set after successful insert to database. See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: Got it, thanks: Db::$inserted_id = $this->insert_id;